# Not able to launch firefox using selenium RC

Tags: python, selenium-rc

I started selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0 server. I have python 2.7. I also downloaded selenium package. When I run this script I expect Firefox should be launched. But nothing happens. Am I missing something?

```
import unittest,selenium

class NewTest(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):

        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox",
                "http://www.google.com/")
        self.selenium.start()

    def test_new(self):

        self.selenium.open("/")
        selenium.type("q","selenium rc")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
```

Comment: Try calling `NewTest.setUp()`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this instead?

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class NewTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_new(self):
        self.browser.get("http://www.google.com")
        elem = self.browser.switch_to_active_element()
        elem.send_keys('some search query')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()
```

Note, for testing stuff like this, I would err to use BDD testing (perhaps with `lettuce`) instead...